# OCS 2007 R2: Any way to login into a Group Chat using UCC API?

Tags: ocs

I'm looking for a way to log into a persistent group chat room created in R2 Chat Server.  Can UCC handle this or do I need a different library?

The OCS people have a [group chat API](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c3dc291c-db47-47e8-9964-0c077776ddb0), but it won't run on XP!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the persistent chat rooms are just IM MCUs. If you have the MCU Uris, you can join the chat room just like you join a conference.

I don't have a clue on how you'll get the history, though.